# Mongodb, mongoose on nodejs, saving photo in db

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a problem with saving default photo in my mongodb. User can upload photo and it's saving in db with no problems. But I want to add a default photo, when user didn't upload his photo.
This is the part of code I added:

```
busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
  console.log("file");
    defaultPhoto = false;
    file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
    newProfile.photo.contentType = mimetype;
});

busboy.on('field', (fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated, encoding, mimetype) => {
  if(fieldname == "voice") {
    newProfile.voice.data = val;
    newProfile.voice.contentType = 'audio/webm';
  } else {
    newProfile[fieldname] = val;
  }
});

busboy.on('finish', () => {
  if(defaultPhoto) {
    newProfile.photo.contentType = 'image/png';
    newProfile.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/../images/', "profile-default.png"));

  } else {
    newProfile.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(saveTo);
    fs.unlink(saveTo);
  }
  newProfile.alias = newProfile.firstName + "" + newProfile.surname;
  newProfile.alias = newProfile.alias.toLowerCase();
  Profile.addProfile(newProfile, (err) => {
    if(err) console.log(err);
  })
```

With this code, uploading working ok, but when user didn't upload his photo I have error :
ValidationError: Profile validation failed: photo: Cast to Object failed for value "null" at path "photo"

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, it's usually not a good idea to store images in a database for performance reasons. It would be better to store the images on your server and then store references to them in your database.

Secondly, I am guessing that this line is causing the problem:

```
newProfile.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname + '/../images/', "profile-default.png"));
```

`newProfile.photo.data` is getting set to `null` because the call to `readFileSync` is returning `null`. Check that you actually have the default profile photo stored in the directory that you are passing to it.

Comment: Thanks for Your answer, I decide to first option :)